# Is "There won't be anything happen to ..." grammatically correct?

Tags: negation, future-tense, existentials

> "There won't be anything happen to ..."

I saw this on an article. It sounds weird to me. I tried to search on Google with the exact phrase and saw lots of results. I wonder if it's correct. I think there should be "that" between "anything" and "happens" or maybe "something happening". Normally, I always use "nothing will happen" though.

Comment: Lots of results?  I get a total of 4 results from google search: ["there won't be anything happen to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=“There+won%27t+be+anything+happen+to").  It's not grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the suggestions on this page are not grammatically valid. In fact, the phrase you propose is **not** grammatical. Since you don't provide context, I'll do my best to narrow things down for you.

> There won't be anything happening to her

Is possible (i.e. is grammatical), though unlikely. This would probably be a sentence uttered by someone assuring another person of the safety of a female in the sense of

> Don't worry. There won't be anything happening to her (Nothing will happen/is happening to her)

It could also be:

> There won't be anything that happens to... (e.g. interfere with the process)

Using "[happens to](http://thefreedictionary.com/happen)" in the sense of "to chance", giving us

> There won't be anything that **might** interfere with the process.

Unless you provide more context (i.e. the article where you found it) I won't be able to help further. I can just confirm the phrase is **not** grammatical.

Comment: +1 There is also a construction which has largely disappeared from standard speech and writing but is still alive in some dialects (mine, for instance): *There won't anything happen to her*. If your dialect doesn't use this it may sound odd; but it is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the observation - I'll look that one up. Hopefully OP can tell us where he/she found it to see if that is indeed the phrase.

Answer (score -2):

If you use **wont**, [it means](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/WONT) *an established custom.* So, it's 'won't' (will not) in this case. But indeed, this is a good question and tricky as well. I'll try though.

> There won't be anything happen to me/her/them/whomsoever... - is grammatical.

Think this way and it'll make it clear.

> What will happen to her? 
>   Will there be anything happen to her? 
>   Don't worry, **there won't be anything happen** to her (i.e. nothing will happen to her).

Comment: I'm afraid not.  "Will there be anything happen to her" is also ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailplane is right. You can say "Will anything happen to her", but you can't say *"Will there be anything happen to her" - it would have to be "Will there be anything happening to her" (though that sounds a tad awkward, and I'd definitely use "Will anything happen to her" over that option)